# Watching folder for changes - bash efficiency

Tags: bash

I've got this:

```
#!/bin/bash

while :
do

SUM=$(tree | md5sum)

if [ "$SUMOLD" != "$SUM" ]; then

# do something here

SUMOLD=$SUM
sleep 1

fi

done
```

Which works just fine. But, the problem is that it consumes 50% of the CPU, a Core2 Duo T8300. Why is that? How to improve the efficiency?

Comment: What operating system are you using? Have you looked into [inotify](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inotify)?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The reason is that the script is continuously running even when the command sleep is called. My recommendation is to launch your script using the "inotifywait" or the "watch" (Alternative solution) command and avoid to use the while loop.

See: http://linux.die.net/man/1/watch

An example taken from the MAN pages:

To watch the contents of a directory change, you could use

```
watch -d ls -l
```

Watch is going to launch your script periodically but without continuously execute your script.

Comment: `watch` is no different than while+sleep.

Comment: It isn't. There is no CPU spike.

Comment: watch uses system interrupts, so is not continously executed like while+sleep, however I have to admit that inotifywait is more elegant solution.

Comment: What do you mean it "uses system interrupts"? It is exactly like while+sleep. A sleeping program uses no CPU, same as watch.

Comment: John, I just checked the watch source code (http://procps.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/procps/procps/watch.c?revision=1.16&view=markup) and you are right, it is using unconditional "for" and the "usleep", so basically is a while+sleep. I thought that this program was using programmable timers. The funny thing is that it looks like "watch" is more efficient than running the bash script. I apologize for my mistake.

Answer (score 5):

This is a job for `inotifywait`. inotify is Linux's event-based system for monitoring files and directories for changes. Goodbye polling loops!

> **NAME**
>          `inotifywait` - wait for changes to files using inotify
>
> **SYNOPSIS**
>
> ```
> inotifywait [-hcmrq] [-e <event> ] [-t <seconds> ] [--format <fmt> ]
>             [--timefmt <fmt> ] <file> [ ... ]
> ```
>
> **DESCRIPTION**
>          `inotifywait`  efficiently waits for changes to files using Linux's `inotify(7)` interface.  It is suitable for waiting for changes to
>          files from shell scripts.  It can either exit once an event occurs, or continually execute and output events as they occur.

Here's how you could write a simple loop which detects whenever files are added, modified, or deleted from a directory:

```
inotifywait -mq /dir | while read event; do
    echo "something happened in /dir: $event"
done
```

Take a look at the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/inotifywait) for more options. If you only care about modifications and want to ignore files simply being read, you could use `-e` to limit the types of events.

Comment: Your loop goes indefinitely on my system. Linux, zsh. I'm executing tree.

Comment: Right. It's an infinite loop, just like your original program.

Answer (score 1):

While a OS specific solution like `inotify` would be better, you can dramatically improve your script by moving the sleep out of the `if` statement:

```
#!/bin/bash

while :
do
  SUM=$(tree | md5sum)    
  if [ "$SUMOLD" != "$SUM" ]; then
    # do something here    
    SUMOLD=$SUM
    # move sleep from here
  fi
  sleep 1 # to here
done
```

CPU usage should drop dramatically now that you're always checking once per second, instead of as often as possible when there are no changes. You can also replace `tree` with `find`, and sleep for longer between each check.